# c# why do I get the same output using classes?

Tags: c#, oop

Ive written code that sorts the given input but after it returns the sorted input it will always return the same output. I'm creating console applications using .NET 5.0 (current) in Visual Studio.

When I give as input "Car Apple Banana" it get sorted in words.Sorted()

After that I print out the original input but it seems to be sorted too. I don't know why because I never sort it.

When the input is: "Car Apple Banana"

The output I now get is:

Apple Banana Car

Apple Banana Car

While it needs to be:

Apple Banana Car

Car Apple Banana

Here's the main code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _10_Words
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input_1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            Words words = new Words(input_1);

            Console.WriteLine(words.Sorted());
            Console.WriteLine(words.Normal());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _10_Words
{
    class Words
    {
        public string[] Output { get; set; }

        public Words(string[] input)
        {
            Output = input;
        }

        public string Sorted()
        {
            string[] sorted = Output;

            Array.Sort(sorted);

            string sorted_array = string.Join(" ", sorted);
            return Convert.ToString(sorted_array);
        }

        public string Normal()
        {
            string[] normal = Output;

            string normal_output = string.Join(" ", normal);
            return Convert.ToString(normal_output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `Normal()` first.  Your `Sorted()` call is changing the array.

Comment: `string[] sorted = Output` isn't copying the *array*, it's just copying a *reference* to the array into a new variable. So, yes, when you sort, you're sorting the one array that actually exists.

Comment: @LarsTech , I am going to add more different classes to it so that wouldn't help

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how do I make it copy the actual array?

Comment: You have to use Array.Copy. Check the .NET-Doc for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you assume that the line

```
string[] sorted = Output;
```

copies `input` to `Output`, whereupon youc an sort `Output` while leaving `input` unchanged.

**This is not the case.**

Arrays are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). As such, when you assign an array like `Output` to another array variable such as `sorted`, `sorted` and `Output` will reference *the same array*.

If you want a copy, you will have to iterate over the elements or use a helper method, such as [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int32_):

```
sorted = new string[Output.Length];
Array.Copy(Output, sorted, Output.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] sorted = Output;

Array.Sort(sorted);
```

When you call `Array.Sort`, this **modifies** the array you pass into it. Because arrays are passed by reference, `sorted` and `Output` refer to **the same array**, which gets sorted.

In other words, you are changing `Output` when you sort the elements.

The easiest fix is to make sure that you make a **new** array, with the same elements as the old one:

```
// Don't forget to include this at the top of the file
using System.Linq;

string[] sorted = Output.ToArray();

Array.Sort(sorted);
```

Another solution is to change your sorting to a method which does not alter the input array and returns you a new (sorted) array:

```
// Don't forget to include this at the top of the file
using System.Linq;

string[] sorted = Output.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Both of these solutions use LINQ, which makes array (and list) operations much nicer to read (IMHO).

Comment: Oh okay so if I get it right when I made sorted = output it was actually referring to the real value of output and changing it. So I need to make a copy of the output so it can be re-used. @O. R. Mapper has posted another answer in wich is a link to reference types, I'll be sure to check that out. This will help me forward in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
string[] sorted = Output;
```

you are assigning a reference to the array Output to sorted, then you sort iy in place with

```
Array.Sort(sorted);
```

but since sorted is just a reference to Output, you are actually sorting Output. A better way is to just print the original array as it comes, then sort it in place and then print it.

Comment: ive noticed that while messing around with the code, but this would not be helpfull since I will be adding more refrences to the word class wich will also change the output.